# How does a server notify a mobile application of a state change

Tags: ios, client-server, state

lets suppose I have a PHP web service, and I have an iphone app that communicates with it. If the iPhone want info from the web services, it makes an http call to the server ans retrieves information. But how do you do this the other way around, how does would the server notify the  the application when some state has changed, and what is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is Push Notifications. You will need to create a push notification server that will send notifications to your users. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: I've read that push notifications can be a little strange for this, ie if the app crashes, also the server has to store the device id. I guise im looking for more of like a shared object kind of thing, where a buch of ios clients are looking at a value, and when it is changed, they are all notified

Comment: push notifications work even when the app is closed. What you are wanting to do in the above comment will cause users to keep the application open and continually pinging the server to see if a value changes.